# How to check if the app is minimized in background in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is there an API to check if the app is minimized but haven't being killed yet so it's in background?

I googled it and also also search in GitHub issues, couldn't fine one.

Does such API exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add `WidgetsBindingObserver` mixin to one or more of your widgets and listen to `AppLifecycleState`.

[Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) is documentation and example

Comment: Great example for cases in which you need such knowledge in the UI (widgets) themselves. Do you have any hints as to how to listen to these states in the logic of the app - i.e. in a Cubit or Block. My need is to pause periodic refetching of API data by a Cubit repository when the app is in the background.... Thanks in anticipation!